# How Do I Fix This Menu?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, event-handling, dom-events

I'm still a beginner, but I've managed to put the following portfolio site together because I want to start blogging.

https://steviebrooks.github.io/folioSite.io/#home

I've had great feedback on the design, but I'm having issues with the menu when I access the site from a mobile device. My mentor advised me to include this code [image] but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Basically, I just want the menu to disappear once the user has selected an option.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Cheers!

I asked my mentor for help and expected the problem to be solved, given that he is a professional. I am now going to experiment with different commands but will be surprised if I can fix this by myself. I have been practicing Javascript for one month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you,

```css
   .dropbtn {
      background-color: #04aa6d;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: none;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content:hover a {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover ~ .dropdown-content a{
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #04aa6d;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      let dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
      let menu = document.querySelector(".dropdown-content");

      dropdown.onmouseover = function (ev) {
        menu.style.display = "block";
      };

      for (let item of menu.children) {
        item.onclick = function (ev) {
          menu.style.display = "none";
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://steviebrooks.github.io/folioSite.io/#home appears to be working perfectly when viewed on a small screen (mobile). Clicking a menu item does cause the submenu to disappear. It's only the large screen version that isn't working and that's because you've only implemented the fix on the `smallnav`. You can apply a similar fix to the `mainnav` by doing the following.

Add to `script.js`

```
function mainMenuFunc() {
    const subMenu = document.querySelector(".mainnav li ul");
    subMenu.style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(() => {
        subMenu.style.display = '';
    }, 100);
}
```

and change

```
<nav class="mainnav">
    <ul>
        <li>
```

to

```
<nav class="mainnav">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="mainMenuFunc()">
```

Comment: This has worked like a charm. Thanks you very much for taking the time to respond. This would have taken me till Christmas to figure out otherwise. Honestly, thanks a million! :-)